# CPU Load balancing for hosting dedicated servers

Tags: cpu, load-balancer

I have been selling web hosts since 2007. I have  been using hostgator's reseller packs. I am a totally "newbie" for dedicated servers. Thats why I am using reseller pack.

Now, I'd like to buy 3 dedicated servers. CPU usage is my biggest nightmare.

I'd like to make CPU load balance between 3 dedicated servers. For example: if first dedicated's CPU load is 100%, it must use second dedicated's CPU. If second one's CPU is full too, first and second must use third dedicated's CPU.

Well, is it possible?  And if yes, how do you call this system (I'm gonna research on the Google)?  Is it CPU load balancing system?  I'vebeen researching on the google for long times and cannot find anything.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really possible on such a small environment/setup.

And without being too rude, if you don't know what you are doing, you may just want to find another host/dedicated provider that can help you, or install an all in one control panel.

As for how to do what you want, it really depends what you are offering.

If you are just serving static HTML sites (or php/whatever, just not with a database), it is easy to have DNS Load Balancing through [Round Robin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS). This will make sure that each server has an almost equal load.

If you have a database, this is where it gets very awkward for small infrastructures. You can have one database server that both machines go to, whilst still using DNS Load Balancing between the other two, but, it isn't ideal.

There isn't really much more I can say... but... I highly suggest you look at a all in one control panel, whilst it may cost a bit, it will do the majority of the hard work for you.

All this being said, unless you are doing something very CPU intensive such as video converting/streaming, I suspect you would reach the maximum bandwidth of your host well before the CPU on the machine gets used up - especially if you are currently on a single reseller account (which probably has up to a few hundred others resellers on the same box).

Comment: +1: For three machines, the overhead isn't worth it.